# Gorilla mux - modify request before passing it to routers

Tags: go, routes, gorilla, mux

Is there a way to catch a `*http.Request` object before It will be parsed and forwarded to [Gorilla mux router](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) handler?

For example, we have some routing map with their handlers:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/products/{key}", ProductHandler)
r.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/", ArticlesCategoryHandler)
```

I plan to use a dynamic language prefix (2 symbols). Example:

without language code (for default language option):

```
https://example.com/products/1
https://example.com/articels/2
```

with language code:

```
https://example.com/ru/products/1
https://example.com/ru/articels/2
```

Is there a way to catch full URL in the middleware, extract language (if exists) and then after some modifications pass It to Gorilla mux routers? It will help to build beautiful URLs:

```
https://example.com/products/1 <- default language
https://example.com/ru/products/1 <- russian language (same resource but in different language)
```

That looks more attractive than this variant:

```
https://example.com/en/products/1 <- mandatory default language
https://example.com/ru/products/1 <- russian language
```

Comment: Use `http.ServeMux` and register a handler under the `"/"` pattern, then have the handler do whatever and after that execute the gorilla mux's `ServeHTTP` method passing it the `w` and `r`.

Comment: @mkopriva, very interesting solution. Can you write an answer? I will accept It

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will probably work:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/products/{key}", ProductHandler)
r.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/", ArticlesCategoryHandler)

m := http.NewServeMux()
m.HandeFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // do something with req
    r.ServeHTTP(w, req)
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", m)
```